# it is posible to get anotehr address from using pre-name on url?

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

If for example I have site call

> xyz.com

how can I force my server(Asp.net/iis) 
to go to another page if i ask for

> a.xyz.com

it is posible?
for example: m.xyz.com leads to xyz.com/mobile.aspx
 thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution involves multiple steps:

1. You need to configure the subdomain in your DNS.
2. You need to create a website in IIS to handle the subdomain. There's a guide [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx) on how to do this. Pay attention to the "Host Header" part - That's where you set you m.xyz.com address.
3. You need to setup an HTTP redirect (301 / 302). You can do this from the config file with the httpRedirect element (More details [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect)).